# LINQ2SQL Any(), NOT EXISTS Problems

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a problem with my linq2sql while grabbing rows from database by condition `select n rows from table1 where table2 doesn't contain any rows by condition table1.id != table2.accId and table1.action != "action_constant"` i have such a code in my c#:

```
query = (from accsArray in db.Accs
         where accsArray.Valid == 1 &&
               !String.IsNullOrEmpty(accsArray.Password) && 
               accsArray.vip_rec == 0 || accsArray.data_col == null &&
               !db.Reaktors.Any(rk => rk.Action == action &&
                                      rk.Account_id == accsArray.id)

         select new DbAcc
         {
             id = accsArray.id,
             Login = accsArray.Login,
             Password = accsArray.Password,
             System = accsArray.System,
             //FriendsCount = Convert.ToInt32(accsArray.Friends_count)
         }).Take(count).OrderBy(acc => acc.id);
```

`!db.Reaktors.Any(rk => rk.Action == action && rk.Account_id == accsArray.id)` this doesn't work, while looking for my clean sql code i see this:

```
SELECT [t2].[id], [t2].[Login], [t2].[System], [t2].[Password]
FROM (SELECT TOP (50) [t0].[id], [t0].[Login], [t0].[System], [t0].[Password]
      FROM [Collider].[dbo].[Accs] AS [t0]
      WHERE (([t0].[Valid] = 1)
             AND ([t0].[Password] <> '')
             AND ([t0].[Login] <> '')
             AND ([t0].[data_col] = 0))
         OR (([t0].[data_col] IS NULL)
             AND (NOT (EXISTS(SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                              FROM [dbo].[Reaktor] AS [t1]
                              WHERE [t1].[Actionself] = '_take_acc_dc'
                                AND ([t1].[Account_id] = [t0].[id])))))) AS [t2]
ORDER BY [t2].[id]
```

I'm afraid of `SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]        FROM [dbo].[Reaktor]` especially of `NULL AS [EMPTY]` so i think that's why it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: You might need to add parenthesis around your `||` clause: `(accsArray.vip_rec == 0 || accsArray.data_col == null)`

Comment: @DigitalD it doesn't work

Comment: We need more information than "it doesn't work".

Comment: What do you mean "To take 1 account"? Please share the actual code you are trying to use that is throwing an error.

Comment: no, i have just tryed to take 2 accs and it selects each time the same 2 accounts

Comment: @DigitalD i'll paste it to pastebin

Comment: @DigitalD http://pastebin.com/9JTrAc1S

Comment: FWIW, "SELECT NULL AS.." should be fine since its in an EXISTS and is only trying to establish the result of the .Any clause. Does this SQL work as is if you substitute suitable parameters into it?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError it gives me an error that `data_col` column `does not exist` so i can't check

Comment: but it exists i know and i see it in my table designer

Comment: @DigitalD it doesn't throw in error in my program's log i see that it is taking the same row many times

Comment: http://data2.floomby.com/files/share/5_3_2013/4DV0Ro98REWinMdkNakXQ.png here you can see a lot of rows with id's 19 and 21 so the program took account from `accs` with id 19 and id 21 many times but there must be only one row with this id per 1 account

Comment: I have updated my sql syntax part of question, and it still takes accs which are in Reaktor table

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Tr53W4qv here is a right t-sql syntax

Comment: that's all i have fixed it, all was in paranthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to place paranthesis right and to order conditions. The good working code will look like this:

```
query = (from accsArray in db.Accs
         where !db.Reaktors.Any(rk => (rk.Actionself == action 
                                       && rk.Account_id == accsArray.id)) 
               && accsArray.Valid == 1 
               && accsArray.Password != String.Empty 
               && accsArray.Login != String.Empty 
               && accsArray.data_col == 0
         select new DbAcc
         {
             id = accsArray.id,
             Login = accsArray.Login,
             Password = accsArray.Password,
             System = accsArray.System,
         }).Take(count).OrderBy(acc => acc.id);
```